# Changing interface for char USB driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, char, driver, linux-device-driver

I write a char driver for a HID USB device.

My goal is to send data to the interface 0.
All the data I want to send are correct, however I send the URB_CONTROL out to the interface 1.

My code is based on skeleton and examples provided by http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2007/04/writing-a-linux-kernel-driver-for-an-unknown-usb-device/.

In which part of the driver (probe, write, etc...) is the interface number specified?

Comment: Is it an academical purpose? Otherwise there already plenty of HID drivers in the kernel, and one of them even might be tweaked to support your device.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I try to support an unsupported USB HID device. I have the driver on Windows. My goal is to transfer data to the device, I manage to do this.

Comment: HID protocol is documented and we have a generic driver for it. You have to add only an extension AFAIUC.